# No se dispara el evento click de la librería Sweet Alert en código Javascript

Tags: javascript, eventos, click, sweetalert2, listener

Tengo este código donde intento hacer que funcione la librería Sweet Alert y no consigo que lo haga... debería funcionar al hacer click en el botón de compra de cualquiera de los productos, pero por más que pruebo, no encuentro el error... me imagino que es porque se repite varias veces el id "compra" en el archivo html y esto es contraproducente al código javascript. Quizás se debería pintar estos botones en el DOM recorriendo un array con un forEach con un solo id, pero quisiera saber si el error del por qué no funciona en este instante el Sweet Alert es justamente ese...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Tipografias -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;300;400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Css Aos -->
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Css Principal -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilo.css"/>
    <title>Productos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- header -->
    <header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html">
                        <img src="../assets/img/logo.png" width="200" height="100" alt="logo" class="logoPrincipal">
                        </a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- fin header -->
    <!-- section -->
    <section>
        <!--div corsets-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
            <h2>Corsets</h2>
                <div>
                    <img src="../assets/img/corset1.jpg" alt="corset1" class="productos" data-aos="flip-left" ata-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic"
                    data-aos-duration="3000"> 
                    <button id="compra">Comprar</button>
                    <img src="../assets/img/corset2.jpg" alt="corset2" class="productos" data-aos="flip-up" ata-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic"
                    data-aos-duration="3000">
                    <button id="compra">Comprar</button>
                    <img src="../assets/img/corset3.jpg" alt="corset3" class="productos" data-aos="flip-right" ata-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic"
                    data-aos-duration="3000">
                    <button id="compra">Comprar</button>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>               
    <!--fin div corsets-->
    <!--div carteras-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
            <h2>Carteras</h2>
                <div>
                    <img src="../assets/img/cartera1.jpg"  alt="cartera1" class="productos" data-aos="flip-left" ata-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic"
                    data-aos-duration="3000">
                    <button id="compra">Comprar</button>
                    <img src="../assets/img/cartera2.jpg"  alt="cartera2" class="productos" data-aos="flip-right" ata-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic"
                    data-aos-duration="3000">
                    <button id="compra">Comprar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>         
    <!--fin div carteras-->
    </section>
    <!-- Fin Section-->
    <!-- Css Aos -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script>
        AOS.init();
    </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>







const compra = document.getElementById ('compra');

compra.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Realizar compra!',
        text: 'Haz click en el boton!',
        icon: 'success',
        confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar'
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, el problema es porque estás usando ID en lugar de clases y `document.getElementById()` te devuelve solo un elemento, por lo que asignas el evento solo al primer botón. Al menos ese sí debería mostrar la ventana modal.

Cambia `id="compra"` por `class="compra"` para obtenerlos todos con [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) y recorres para agregar evento a cada botón, de preferencia, con una función aparte.

No es suficiente con mostrar la ventana modal, también debes asegurarte de que el usuario hizo clic en el botón "Aceptar". Solo encadena el resultado de la promesa agregando `.then()` con una función para identificar cuál fue la acción del usuario.

```js
// Obtener todos los botones con clase compra
const compras = document.querySelectorAll('.compra');

// Crear función para mostrar alerta
function comprar(e) {
    // e.target es el botón que recibió clic
    // Necesitas acceder a la imagen para tomar los datos desde ahí
    let img = e.target.previousElementSibling;
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Realizar compra!',
        text: 'Haz click en el boton!',
        icon: 'success',
        confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar'
    // Encadena la promesa para saber lo que pasó en la ventana modal
    }).then(resp => {
        if(resp.isConfirmed) {
            // El usuario hizo clic en el botón aceptar
            // Necesitas agregar información adicional en alguna parte
            console.log(img.alt);
        } else {
            // El usuario cerró la ventana modal sin hacer clic en el botón aceptar
        }
    });;
}

// Recorrer botones para asignar función
compras.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', comprar));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Tipografias -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;300;400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Css Aos -->
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Css Principal -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilo.css"/>
    <title>Productos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- header -->
    <header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html">
                        <img src="../assets/img/logo.png" width="200" height="100" alt="logo" class="logoPrincipal">
                        </a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- fin header -->
    <!-- section -->
    <section>
        <!--div corsets-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
            <h2>Corsets</h2>
                <div>
                    <img src="../assets/img/corset1.jpg" alt="corset1" class="productos" data-aos="flip-left" ata-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic"
                    data-aos-duration="3000"> 
                    <button class="compra">Comprar</button>
                    <img src="../assets/img/corset2.jpg" alt="corset2" class="productos" data-aos="flip-up" ata-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic"
                    data-aos-duration="3000">
                    <button class="compra">Comprar</button>
                    <img src="../assets/img/corset3.jpg" alt="corset3" class="productos" data-aos="flip-right" ata-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic"
                    data-aos-duration="3000">
                    <button class="compra">Comprar</button>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>               
    <!--fin div corsets-->
    <!--div carteras-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
            <h2>Carteras</h2>
                <div>
                    <img src="../assets/img/cartera1.jpg"  alt="cartera1" class="productos" data-aos="flip-left" ata-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic"
                    data-aos-duration="3000">
                    <button class="compra">Comprar</button>
                    <img src="../assets/img/cartera2.jpg"  alt="cartera2" class="productos" data-aos="flip-right" ata-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic"
                    data-aos-duration="3000">
                    <button class="compra">Comprar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>         
    <!--fin div carteras-->
    </section>
    <!-- Fin Section-->
    <!-- Css Aos -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script>
        AOS.init();
    </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Tienes que agregar datos, ya sea en el botón o la imagen para identificar el producto que quiere comprar el usuario y poder agregarlo a la compra. En este ejemplo solo estoy accediendo al atributo `alt` de la imagen, pero puedes usar [atributos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), por ejemplo:

```
<img src="corset2" data-id="id_del_producto">
<button class="compra" data-id="id_del_producto">Comprar</button>
```

No es necesario que lo pongas en los dos, solo en uno, tú decides si en la imagen o el botón. En Javascript lo obtienes con:

```
// Si es desde la imagen
let id = img.dataset.id;
// Si es desde el botón
let id = e.target.dataset.id;
```

Insisto, solo debes usar uno, si incluyes estas dos líneas vas a obtener error por tratar de definir dos veces la misma variable.